# Understanding how to memcpy with TheUnsafe

Tags: java, pointers, garbage-collection, memcpy

I read stuff about TheUnsafe, but I get confused by the fact that, unlike C/C++ we have to work out the offset of stuff, and there's also the 32bits VM vs the 64bits VM, which may or may not have different pointers sizes depending on a particular VM setting being turned on or off (also, I'm assuming all offsets to data are actually based on pointer arithmetic this would influence them to).

Unfortunately, it seems all the stuff ever written about how to use TheUnsafe stems from one article only (the one who happened to be the first) and all the others copy pasted from it to a certain degree. Not many of them exist, and some are not clear because the author apparently did not speak English.

My question is:

How can I find the offset of a field + the pointer to the instance that owns that field (or field of a field, or field, of a field, of a field...) using TheUnsafe

How can I use it to perform a memcpy to another pointer + offset memory address

Considering the data may have several GB in size, and considering the heap offers no direct control over data alignment and it may most certainly be fragmented because:

1) I don't think there's nothing stoping the VM from allocating  field1 at offset + 10 and field2 at offset sizeof(field1) + 32, is there?

2) I would also assume the GC would move big chunks of data around, leading to a field with 1GB in size being fragmented sometimes.

So is the memcpy operation as I described even possible?

If data is fragmented because of GC, of course the heap has a pointer to where the next chunk of data is, but using the simple process described above doesn't seem to cover that.

so must the data be off-heap for this to (maybe) work? If so, how to allocate off-heap data using TheUnsafe, making such data work as a field of an instance and of course freeing the allocated memory once done with it?

I encourage anyone who didn't quite understand the question to ask for any specifics they need to know.

I also urge people to refrain from answering if their whole idea is "put all objects you need to copy in an array and use`System.arraycopy`. I know it's common practice in this wonderful forum to, instead of answering what's been asked, offering a complete alternate solution that, in principle, has nothing to do with the original question apart from the fact that it gets the same job done.

Best regards.

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of the way the language is designed to be used?

Comment: Mainly out of curiosity (knowing the limits of what can and can't be done), but also because I happen to be writing a piece software that needs to work with big sound files and to process images in real time at the same time using what's a probably overly complex algorith of mine, and, as it is now, my proof of concept runs slower than 60fps, and I think this may improve performance. I have no academical knowledge, so the best I can do to improve algorithms is the very basics (avoid too many instantiations, inline stuff when possible, using bit shifting instead of arithmetics if possible, etc)

Comment: have you read its javadocs or looked at code using it, e.g. on github or in the jdk itself?

Comment: Fields can only be of primitive types or object references, so they can never be more than 8 bytes each (for long, double and maybe references on 64 bit VMs). What could be 1GB is an array, if that is moved be the garbage collector it will be moved as a whole.

Comment: @ThomasKläger yes. But the reference is a pointer to a real memory address that contains data and some meta information about the type of such data. I was wondering if you could, using TheUnsafe, get a hold of that address and do some sort of memcpy. There should be a way. memcpy is just a function to interface with the same inbuilt functionality of hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a big warning: **“Unsafe must die”** http://blog.takipi.com/still-unsafe-the-major-bug-in-java-6-that-turned-into-a-java-9-feature/

## Some prerequisites

```
static class DataHolder {
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int i3;
    DataHolder d1;
    DataHolder d2;
    public DataHolder(int i1, int i2, int i3, DataHolder dh) {
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
        this.i3 = i3;
        this.d1 = dh;
        this.d2 = this;
    }
}

Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);

DataHolder dh1 = new DataHolder(11, 13, 17, null);
DataHolder dh2 = new DataHolder(23, 29, 31, dh1);
```

## The basics

To get the offset of a field (i1), you can use the following code:

```
Field fi1 = DataHolder.class.getDeclaredField("i1");
long oi1 = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(fi1);
```

and the access the field value of instance dh1 you can write

```
System.out.println(unsafe.getInt(dh1, oi1)); // will print 11
```

You can use similar code to access an object reference (d1):

```
Field fd1 = DataHolder.class.getDeclaredField("d1");
long od1 = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(fd1);
```

and you can use it to get the reference to dh1 from dh2:

```
System.out.println(dh1 == unsafe.getObject(dh2, od1)); // will print true
```

## Field ordering and alignment

To get the offsets of all declared fields of a object:

```
for (Field f: DataHolder.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (!Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
        System.out.println(f.getName()+" "+unsafe.objectFieldOffset(f));
    }
}
```

On my test it seems that the JVM reorders fields as it sees fit (i.e. adding a field can yield completely different offsets on the next run)

## An Objects address in native memory

It's important to understand that the following code is going to crash your JVM sooner or later, because the Garbage Collector will move your objects at random times, without you having any control on when and why it happens.

Also it's important to understand that the following code depends on the JVM type (32 bits versus 64 bits) and on some start parameters for the JVM (namely, usage of compressed oops on 64 bit JVMs).

On a 32 bit VM a reference to an object has the same size as an int. So what do you get if you call `int addr = unsafe.getInt(dh2, od1));` instead of `unsafe.getObject(dh2, od1))`? Could it be the native address of the object?

Let's try:

```
System.out.println(unsafe.getInt(null, unsafe.getInt(dh2, od1)+oi1));
```

will print out `11` as expected.

On a 64 bit VM without compressed oops (-XX:-UseCompressedOops), you will need to write

```
System.out.println(unsafe.getInt(null, unsafe.getLong(dh2, od1)+oi1));
```

On a 64 bit VM with compressed oops (-XX:+UseCompressedOops), things are a bit more complicated. This variant has 32 bit object references that are turned into 64 bit addresses by multiplying them with 8L:

```
System.out.println(unsafe.getInt(null, 8L*(0xffffffffL&(dh2, od1)+oi1));
```

## What is the problem with these accesses

The problem is the Garbage Collector together with this code. The Garbage Collector can move around objects as it pleases. Since the JVM knows about it's object references (the local variables dh1 and dh2, the fields d1 and d2 of these objects) it can adjust these references accordingly, your code will never notice.

By extracting object references into int/long variables you turn these object references into primitive values that happen to have the same bit-pattern as an object reference, but the Garbage Collector does not know that these were object references (they could have been generated by a random generator as well) and therefore does not adjust these values while moving objects around. So as soon as a Garbage Collection cycle is triggered your extracted addresses are no longer valid, and trying to access memory at these addresses might crash your JVM immediately (the good case) or you might trash your memory without noticing on the spot (the bad case).

Comment: so If all these large chunks of data are allocated outside the managed heap using theUnsafe and then deleted, I don't have the problem with the GC. But how would that be done? does theUnsafe gives me a pointer for the data I just allocated? is there a function I can use that's similar to memcpy, considering I have that off-heap address?

Comment: For implementing your own memory management there are the functions `allocateMemory` (which returns the address of the allocated memory block), `copyMemory` for copying data and `freeMemory` to free the memory again. See for example http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html @FinnTheHuman