# Is it possible to get a physical address of an object in Java?

Tags: java

Reference variable stores reference to an object. It seems that the only way to get this reference is calling toString() method which returns the object hashcode but not the address. Is there any way to get object's physical address?

```
class Point {
int x;
int y;
}
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p = new Point();
}
}
```

My question is: "Is it possible to get the physical address of the p object?". And of course I do know that p.toString() returns its hashcode. And that's why I am asking about a possibility to get the address. I do not need to use it or to change it. I just need to know is it possible to get it.

The reason why I am asking the question is that I saw a lot of the same questions in many different places, but no answers. I just need to confirm my suggestion that it is not possible. But in this case the new question arises: how JVM finds the object?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: An object's physical address is not accessible, and can be changed at will by the JVM. That "address" in the toString() is the *identity hash*, not the same thing as address.

Comment: You can use `sun.misc.Unsafe` to get the current physical address of an object (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114099/understanding-how-to-memcpy-with-theunsafe/38189553#38189553). But the garbage collector might kick at that very moment and move the object to some other address. So the address you got might be invalid almost from the moment you get it.

Comment: Why do you care what the physical address is? Even if you could get it, what good would it do?

Comment: Does it have to be useful? Sometimes it's just interesting to know without practical reasons.

Comment: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/dangerous-code-how-to-be-unsafe-with-java-classes-objects-in-memory/ might give you some insight?

Answer (score 0):

> . It seems that the only way to get this reference is calling toString() method which returns the object hashcode but not the address.

The hashCode is a randomly generated number and has nothing to do with the address.

> Is there any way to get object's physical address?

You can get it using Unsafe, but you shouldn't do this for anything other than interest.

> how JVM finds the object?

The JVM uses the reference as an index.  This index could indirect i.e. there could be an array of where the objects are, it could be a translation e.g. CompressedOops might multiply the index by 8 and optionally add an offset.

If you use the Oracle/OpenJDK and you disable CompressedOops, you can get an untranslated 64-bit address.

A simple way to do this is to put the address of an object into an array
and then access the elements of the array as if they were `int` or `long` depending on the size of your references.

```
Object i = 0x12345678;
System.out.printf("indentityHashCode = %08x%n", System.identityHashCode(i));
Object[] obj = {i};
assert Unsafe.ARRAY_OBJECT_INDEX_SCALE == 8; // 8 bytes per reference.
long address = UNSAFE.getLong(obj, (long) Unsafe.ARRAY_OBJECT_BASE_OFFSET);
System.out.printf("%x%n", address);
for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++)
    System.out.printf("%02x ", UNSAFE.getByte(address + j) & 0xFF);
System.out.println();

// now some really scary sh!t
UNSAFE.putLong(i, 8L, UNSAFE.getLong(0L, 8L));
System.out.printf("`i` is now a %s and is %x%n", i.getClass(), i);
```

I have many other examples here

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Performance-Examples/tree/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/unsafe

One of the most useful tricks is being able to see how objects are arranged, before and after a GC.  Only try this at home. NSFW.